# Adding a category to a product doesn't affect the category page in PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I need to add a category to many products in PrestaShop 1.7. I'm using the following code:

```
$add_category= 'INSERT IGNORE INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product (id_category, id_product, position) VALUES ('.$id_category.', '.$id_product.', 0);';
Db::getInstance()->executeS($add_category);
```

This works and adds the appropriate product and category id. But when I check the products on the category page (*mydomain.com/119-namecategory*), they are still the same products.

Even if I remove all products from the `ps_category_product` table that have the category selected, they are still visible on the site (*mydomain.com/119-mycategory*).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Even if I remove all products from the ps_category_product table that have the category selected, they are still visible on the site (mydomain.com/119-mycategory).

Answer (score 0):

You are using executeS. This is only for Select queries (and others that don't "change" the data in database. To Insert (and others that do change), use execute.

```
Db::getInstance()->execute($add_category);
```

Comment: Now I used `Db::getInstance()->execute($add_category);` and added over 60 records to the database, but on the page where all products in a given category are, there are no changes.
I removed the cache in prestashop, removed the cache in files, removed the cache in the browser ...

Comment: Have you check product visibility is set for either "both" or "catalog"?